# How does the @main annotation in Scala 3 w​ork?

Tags: scala, program-entry-point, scala-3

As I was learning Scala 3, I saw a new way to write `main`:

```
@main def main1 =
  println("main1 printed something")
```

I checked source for `@main`, it is just

```
class main extends scala.annotation.Annotation {}
```

What is happening by using `@main` here?

Answer (score 9):

`@main` isn't really doing anything. It's the Scala compiler which does everything. Scala compiler will look for any methods which are marked with `@main` and turn them into java (jvm) entry `static void main` method.

Scala also supports multiple `@main` . It will link every `@main` method to a single `static void` method in a different class.

Besides wiring `@main` method to a java entrypoint, Scala compiler also adds some basic argument parsing. For example , you could do:

```scala
@main def go(name:String, age:Int) = println(s"hello, $name ($age)")
```

and expect it to work via CLI when you pass the name and age.

So `@main` is just really a marker annotation.

*Reference documentation: https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/main-functions.html*